.NET Azure Function in Azure Container App setting the listening port
I'm attempting to host my azure function app inside an azure container app. The app consists of a couple of event grid trigger functions, written in .NET.
It seems to be running locally when started in docker, but when deploying to the container app I'm getting a random listening port:
The TargetPort 80 does not match the listening port 37433.
The TargetPort 80 does not match the listening port 36129.
The TargetPort 80 does not match the listening port 43263
What should this listening port be set by? Thanks.
I've tried:
Running locally inside a docker function
Setting the Target port, but obviously the listening port changes
Setting Environment variables - WEBSITES PORT = 8080, PORT = 8080, ASPNETCORE_URLS = "http://+:8080"
In dockerfile EXPOSE 8080
Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS installer-env

EXPOSE 8080

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
dotnet publish src/MyFunctions/MyFunctions.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]

HostBuilder
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddConsole();
})
.ConfigureServices((b,s) =>
{
    s.AddApplication();
    s.AddInfrastructure(b.Configuration);
})
.Build();

host.Run();

One of my event functions
    [Function("EGHandleBlobCreated")]
public async Task Run([EventGridTrigger] BlobCreatedEvent cloudEvent, FunctionContext context)
{
...
}


@DasariKamali thanks, I've added the dockerfile and relevant code

The error mentioned suggests that the use of a self-signed certificate in your Dockerfile is causing an issue.
To resolve the issue, remove the self-signed certificate, redeploy the image, and ensure to include the target port 80 in the container application’s configurations

App Service has no control about which port your container listens on. What it does need is to know which port to forward requests to. If your container listens to port 80 or 8080, App Service is able to automatically detect it. If it listens to any other port, you need to set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting to the port number, and App Service forwards requests to that port in the container. The WEBSITES_PORT app setting does not have any effect within the container, and you can’t access it as an environment variable within the container.

For more details refer this link

The error TargetPort does not match the listening port indicates that the container is listening on a port different from the one that the Azure Container App is configured to use for incoming traffic.

TargetPort is the port your Azure Container App expects to receive traffic on.
ListeningPort is the port your application inside the container is actually using.


To resolve this error, you need to set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting to the correct port number. App Service will then forward requests to that port within the container. Note that the WEBSITES_PORT setting has no effect inside the container itself and cannot be accessed as an environment variable within the container. You should also allow insecure traffic to your  container app. When this setting is set to true, HTTP requests to port 80 aren't automatically redirected to port 443 using HTTPS.

Make sure that the Ingress settings are configured as shown below:



The bleow is  a sample Dockerfile for setting up Azure Functions in a container:


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp4/FunctionApp4.csproj", "FunctionApp4/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./FunctionApp4/FunctionApp4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp4"
RUN dotnet build "./FunctionApp4.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./FunctionApp4.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true


I used this MSDOC to create my first containerized Azure Functions on Azure Container Apps.

The URL for accessing the function will be similar to the one you find in "Get Function URL" in the Azure Function App of the functions tab:
https://AzureFunctionappname.azurecontainerapps.io/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=FunnctionName&code=key

The function trigger above responds to an event sent by an Event Grid source. You must have an event subscription to the source to receive events. So, I connected the URL to the Event Grid System Topic with Event Subscriptions.


